# Finding the closed form of the following recurrence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I have the recurrence relation

$a_n = a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + 2^n$.

How do I find the closed form of that solution?

Comment: You could use generating functions.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have not learned about that. How would i go about that?

Comment: The generating function method is to find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
a_n=a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}+2^n\tag1
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\underbrace{\left(a_n-\frac12\cdot2^n\right)}_{\large b_n}=\underbrace{\left(a_{n-1}-\frac12\cdot2^{n-1}\right)}_{\large b_{n-1}}-6\underbrace{\left(a_{n-2}-\frac12\cdot2^{n-2}\right)}_{\large b_{n-2}}\tag2
$$
To solve
$$
b_n=b_{n-1}-6b_{n-2}\tag3
$$
we can use the roots of $r^2-r+6=0$, i.e. $r=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{23}}2$, to get solutions in the form
$$
a_n=\frac12\cdot2^n+c_1\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{23}}2\right)^n+c_2\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt{23}}2\right)^n\tag4
$$
Computing $c_1$ and $c_2$ requires a couple of values of $a_n$.

$(4)$ can be written in terms of trigonometric functions:
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=\frac12\cdot2^n+6^{n/2}\,(c_1+c_2)\cos(n\theta)+6^{n/2}\,(c_1-c_2)\,i\sin(n\theta)\\
&=\frac12\cdot2^n+c_1^\prime6^{n/2}\cos(n\theta)+c_2^\prime6^{n/2}\sin(n\theta)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
where $\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac1{2\sqrt6}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

- solve the characteristic equation $x^2-x+6=0$
- it has two roots $r_1$ and $r_2$
- the solutions of homegeneous equation $h_n-h_{n-1}+6h_{n-2}=0$ are $h_n=\alpha(r_1)^n+\beta(r_2)^n$
- but since they are conjugate complexes a more suitable representation is $h_n=r^n(\alpha\cos(n\theta)+\beta\sin(n\theta))$
- find a particular solution of $p_n-p_{n-1}+6p_{n-2}=2^n$. Since $r_i\neq 2$ then you can search it under the form $p_n=\gamma\times2^n$
- the equation being linear then the general solution is $a_n=h_n+p_n$
- enventually determine $\alpha,\beta$ from initial values $a_0,a_1$ (not available for this problem).

Your problem is not the simpler one to begin with because it doesn't have nice coefficients.

To get familiarized with the method, have a look first at the examples provided on this website: [Solving Recurrence Relations](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/222/rec.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

After robjohn's answer, let us consider the more general case of $$a_n = a_{n-1} - k\,a_{n-2} + 2^n$$ Let $$a_n=b_n +\frac{2^{n+2}}{k+2}\implies b_n=b_{n-1}-k\,b_{n-2}$$ So, the characteristic equation is $$r^2=r-k\implies r_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4 k}}{2} $$ You could even let $b_n=2^{-n}\,c_n $ and get $$c_n=2c_{n-1}-4k \,c_{n-2}$$ leading to $$r^2=2r-4k\implies r_{1,2}=1 \pm\sqrt{1-4 k} $$